# Ancient Hardware: IBM Spacesaver II Keyboard with Windows 7 on MacPro

Tags: osx-lion, keyboard, boot-camp, windows-7, mac-pro

I'm running Win 7 on a 2010 MacPro under Bootcamp. I have a classic IBM Spacesaver II keyboard (PS/2 connection) plugged in via a USB adaptor.

I've been running this set-up since I got my first MacPro back in 2007. This year I've started experiencing an issue (possibly related to Lion?) which involves the Windows <kbd>Control</kbd> key.

Although the key isn't physically down on the keyboard, Windows thinks it is so for example pressing <kbd>A</kbd> invokes **Select All** and turning the scroll wheel on my mouse makes text get bigger and smaller.

Sometimes unplugging the keyboard for a bit fixes it, sometimes a restart is required. Swapping the IBM keyboard for the nasty standard modern 'calculator' keyboard one gets from Apple nowadays doesn't have any effect. It is as if something is toggled on and can't be toggled off.

This is starting to drive me mad and is affecting my work, the Apple keyboard won't map to the Windows one as I'd like (e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd> => <kbd>Win</kbd> (windows key) and pops up the Start menu).

Do you know why this is happening and/or if it is fixable?

Comment: Just because this is taking place on a Mac Pro doesn't really make this an Ask Different question. It's either an IBM hardware question, or a Windows question (accessibility -> sticky keys, maybe?).

Comment: The same keyboard doesn't cause any problems when connected to a Windows XP/7 box ...

Comment: What happens with the same hardware when booted into OSX?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet - got code to write :-(

Will try shortly and post the result.

Comment: The same keyboard doesn't cause any problem *when not connected to your Bootcamp'ed box*. Just because it doesn't happen on another Windows computer does not make it a Mac Pro problem. Not to mention, per my suggestion, that doesn't rule out a software (e.g. Sticky Keys) problem either. Basically you changed everything and it worked, but that really didn't narrow the problem down.

Comment: The keyboard + OS X works fine. I'm none the wiser.

@Jason Salaz - don't worry, I'm not dissing Macs (I've had one since 1990).

Comment: The point I'm ultimately making is that this is not on topic for Ask Different, and I feel it should be moved to somewhere more appropriate, likely Super User. But I am also dropping hints (check out all your sticky key settings, disable them and also disable their activation shortcuts if you don't use them).

Comment: I agree with Jason. You're also likely to get a better answer on Super User, as there are many Windows users there. Would you like me to migrate it?